# Separating simple rules from PHP code

Tags: php

At the moment I have some PHP which sets a single variable based on the value of other independent variables in a linear format, like so:

```
$result = 0;

if ($var1 == 'X') {
  $result += 10;
}

if ($var2 < 10) {
  $result += 15;
}
elseif ($var2 > 50) {
  $result -= 50;
}

// more of the same
```

However, I'd like to be able to express these rules in a less programming-like way, mainly so that someone who doesn't know how to program can add/edit rules, and also because I might want to use the same rules in a Python or Perl script, without having to maintain copies in multiple languages. I could write my own simple language (for want of a better word) and parser, but I'd prefer to use an existing solution as that saves work and increases the likelihood that other people will know how to write rules in it.

Is there a sensible/obvious choice for this sort of task?

Comment: +1 For seeing a good place to apply DRY principles

Comment: If each "rule" is made of a "condition" and "assignment", is the "condition" always going to be as simple comparision like `==`, `!=`, `<`, etc? Also, will the "assignment" always be an increment or decrement (`+=` or `-=`)?

Comment: I think "custom language" or "python to php" translator is your choose. The example you've provided is too general.

Comment: Austin: The condition will also be a comparison (or multiple comparisons joined by AND/OR), either of strings (equal or not equal) or integers. The assignments will always be increment or decrement, to leave $result at a single integer value after all the rules have been evaluated.

Comment: Are `$var1` and `$var2` the only variables which are checked? How many of those variables are there?

Comment: Or even better: Tell us what you want! Using some pseudo code with unrealistic variable names isn't good to demonstrate something that shall be made more human readable. So could you tell us what is specified using these rules eventually?

Comment: As I said earlier, all that is specified using these rules is an integer value in $result. There could be any number of rules, I want to go through each one and alter $result accordingly (or not, if the condition isn't met).

Comment: My question was about the `$var1` variables. Is it okay for the end use to write `$var2 > 50`? If not, please further elaborate...

Comment: Yes, it's fine for the end user to write $var2 > 50, preferably without the $ but that's not absolutely critical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need a language/parser for this. You could create an expression builder (similar to how one creates email message filter rules) and store the results in a database. This will also allow other languages to access the stored rules.

Users would add comparisons until satisfied, then enter the associated assignment rule.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't thought of describing what I want as an expression builder and sticking that into Google has pulled up a few potentially useful leads.

Answer (score 1):

Design a little pseudo-language and convert it to PHP code.

```
$var1 == 'X': +10
$var2 < 10:   +15
$var2 > 50:   -50
```

Now you can use the [PHP Tokenizer](http://php.net/manual/en/book.tokenizer.php) to parse this and convert it to real PHP code. Then you should cache the generated code and include it as a PHP file.

This is a really quick and dirty implementation using my own [TokenStream](http://github.com/nikic/tokenstream) class (but you could easily port that to the native tokenizer):

```
<?php
    $code =<<<'EOC'
$var1 == 'X': +10

$var2 < 10:   +15
$var2 > 50:   -50
EOC;

    require '../tokenstream/src/TokenStream.php';

    $tokenStream = new TokenStream('<?php ' . $code);
    $code = '';
    foreach ($tokenStream as $i => $token) {
        if ($token->is(T_OPEN_TAG)) {
            $code .= '<?php $result = 0;' . PHP_EOL . 'if (';
        }
        elseif ($token->is(T_WHITESPACE) && preg_match("[\r\n]", $token->content)) {
            $code .= ';' . $token . 'if (';
        }
        elseif ($token->is(T_COLON)) {
            $code .= ') $result += ';
        }
        else {
            $code .= $token;
        }
    }
    $code .= ';';

    echo '<pre>', htmlspecialchars($code), '</pre>';
```

It is really quick and dirty. You could execute arbitrary code. For a better implementation you would need to implement a state machine and I hadn't got the time right now ;)

Script output:

```
<?php $result = 0;
if ($var1 == 'X') $result +=  +10;

if ($var2 < 10) $result +=    +15;
if ($var2 > 50) $result +=    -50;
```

Comment: That's sort of what I'm looking for, except I hoped there would be an existing solution and one which is language-neutral - I don't really want to have to write a tokeniser for Perl/Python as well.

If the solution involves implementing a state machine I'd rather just keep the rules embedded in PHP, given the workload required. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [Chain of Responsibility](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/chain_of_responsibility) or [Command](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/command) Pattern.

There is also [PHPRules](http://www.swindle.net/rules/) which lets you specify the rules in a language agnostic format.

Answer (score 0):

I would build a simple parse, and use tab delimited text files to store the values.